# show locations in google map using mvc4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, google-maps-api-3

I have show locations in a google map using mvc4. I have a model and I get 10 lat and long values via model. I am using these values in my view side. Here my codes :

```
function showLocation() {
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        zoomControl: true,
        scaleControl: true,
        streetViewControl: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, mapOptions);
    setMarkers(map);
}

function setMarkers(map){
    @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
    {
        <text>
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        map: map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(@item.Latitude, @item.Longitude),
        content: '@item.DateAdded.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss")'
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(@item.Latitude, @item.Longitude),
                map: map,
                title: infowindow.content,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(@item.Latitude, @item.Longitude)
            });
        </text>
    }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', showLocation);
```

when I run this code I get some errors like "You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors." and in my canvas map shown as :[image]

there are 10 locations over and over and map does not appear. So can you say me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. true codes are :

```
function initMap() {
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        zoomControl: true,
        scaleControl: true,
        streetViewControl: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, mapOptions);

    var infoWindows = getinfoWindows(map);
    map.setCenter(infoWindows[0].position);
    //setMarkers(map);
};

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);

function getinfoWindows(map){
    var infos = [];
    @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
    {
        <text>
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        map: map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(@item.Latitude, @item.Longitude),
        content: '@item.DateAdded.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss")'
    });
    infos.push(infowindow);
    </text>
    }
    return infos;
}
```